# ”Just over an hour"

Tags: phrase-meaning

thank you for your all the helps.

[**This issue**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/biden-tells-zelenskyy-u-respond-180216895.html) has been now a world wide concern, which on daily basis is reported in my country too.
And the impact on the market is huge.

I have a naive question.

There is a a passage in the Yahoo News story linked above, saying,

> Biden told Putin in their call Saturday, which **lasted just over an hour,** that the U.S. and its allies and partners “will respond decisively and impose swift and severe costs” should Moscow move on its neighbor, the White House said.

Does "just over an hour" mean the conversation was short? Or "just"(around 5 minutes) "over an hour"? So would it be a neutral?

Thank you for helping me out.(m_m).

Comment: The call lasted more than an hour, but not a lot more. Whether this is long or short depends on the lengths of similar calls.

Comment: +1 on Peter's comment, that's how I'd define it

Comment: @Peter Well..thanks. So "just" "over an hour". Thanks!.

Comment: @Kentaro We say thank you for all your **help** (singular). **Helps** with an **s** is used only as a verb.

Comment: fyi: in formal writing and speaking, I recommend using "one hour" rather than "an hour."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'just over 40,000 dollars' mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/321626/what-does-just-over-40-000-dollars-mean)

Answer (score 2):

"Just over" would mean "longer than (over), but not a *lot* longer than". Just, in this context, meaning "barely" or "slightly".

It's not a very precise phrase, so we can't know exactly how long the call was, but we can find a sensible range. It certainly means that the call was longer than 60 minutes, because it was *over* 1h.

As for the maximum, is almost certain that the call would be less than 90 minutes (1h30) at the very most, and most likely around 60-70 minutes (1h to 1h10)