# What does 'just over 40,000 dollars' mean?

Tags: meaning

Whats does 'just over 40,000 dollars' mean in the following sentence?

> I rent this apartment for just over 40,000 dollars a year.

Does it mean

1. 40,000 dollars a year is no big deal

or

2. the rent is a little more than 40,000 dollars a year?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/309561/just-over-an-hour

Comment: If you say A is is 'just over' B, it just means A is slightly bigger than B. You are saying _nothing_ about whether this is a good or bad thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latter.  "Just" modifies "over" and the phrase "just over" means slightly over.  Compare "well over" or "just under".